# Does Jodit Editor have custom Decorators like draft.js?

Tags: reactjs, jodit

I'm looking for a way to override the render of headings like h2, h3, h4. When the headings are in display mode I'm creating a named anchor on them in the decorator. We are looking to move away from react-wysiwyg which uses draft js. Draft js has custom decorators and I'm looking for the equivalent in Jodit.

thanks in advance

I've checked the documentation and examples but I'm not seeing ability to do this